# How to parameterize AWS bucket name and folder name

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, unix

```
EXPORT AWS_profile=albt_alb_dev;
aws s3 rm s3://albt-alb-prd-us-east-1-raw/albdev/Test/Folder1/ --recursive --exclude "" --profile $AWS_profile;
```

I have given hard-coded value for Bucket name and folder name. I need to parameterize the Bucket name and Folder name used in the above script.

If the Bucket name and Folder name varies, I need to make changes in the script accordingly.

Can anyone guide how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use parameters like this:

```bash
EXPORT AWS_profile=albt_alb_dev;
bucketName="albt-alb-prd-us-east-1-raw"
folderName="Folder1"
aws s3 rm s3://$bucketName/albdev/Test/$folderName/ --recursive --exclude "" --profile $AWS_profile;
```

Or You can pass the parameters to the script:

```bash
EXPORT AWS_profile=albt_alb_dev;
bucketName=$1 #first argument to the script
folderName=$2 #second argument to the script
aws s3 rm s3://$bucketName/albdev/Test/$folderName/ --recursive --exclude "" --profile $AWS_profile;
```

And call it like this:
`./script.sh albt-alb-prd-us-east-1-raw Folder1`
You can parametrize the whole path of course.

Comment: If the Bucket name and Folder name vary, I need to make changes in the script accordingly. Suppose if the folder name is different, the script should take the other folder and execute the script. Can you guide me on that?

Comment: Exactly. If You hardcode these values then You have to change the script. If You use the parametrised script call then You can provide different input every time (second approach described in the answer).

Comment: export AWS_profile=albt_alb_dev;
bucketName=$1
folderName=$2

echo aws s3 rm $bucketName/$folderName/ --recursive --exclude "" --profile $AWS_profile;
aws s3 rm $bucketName/$folderName/ --recursive --exclude "" --profile $AWS_profile;

When I run the above command, I'm getting error stating - fatal error: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist

I'm giving the Bucket name correctly which is - albt-alb-prd-us-east-1-raw

Comment: Please format this correctly. The point is You need to provide the full path with s3://, like: ```s3://$bucketName/$folderName/``` Or You provide bucketName: ```s3://albt-alb-prd-us-east-1-raw```